# How to read enum's int value in jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, enums

How to read Enum's int value in jquery?
I am in need of Enum's int value in jquery, tried

```
public enum MyEnum
{
  [Description("Test1")]
  Test1= 1,

  [Description("Test2")]
  Test2= 2,
}
```

This is my enum, I have to read the int values, so I tried :

```
 '@AppUtility.Enum.MyEnum.Test1'
```

Which essentially gives me the enum string value but not int value. 
So I tried

```
and tried parseInt('@AppUtility.Enum.MyEnum.Test1')
```

Which again gave the same .
Hope there is some way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast it to an int in c# and send the value where you need it in your javascript.

```
@(int)AppUtility.Enum.MyEnum.Test1
```